# What causes this code to throw exception?

Tags: java, debugging

In some unsuccessful attempts to create a calculator in java that follows the BODMAS rule to solve complex mathematical expressions, I decided that it was important I create a method whose argument is a string. Such a method should detect braces and mathematical signs(i.e **plus**, **times**, **minus**, **divide**, **open** and **close** **brackets**) and should convert any string say **temp** that is between any two of the signs above into double say **temp2** unless **temp** is empty(i.e ""). The method then stores **temp2** values and the signs in a list of Objects in the same order as in the argument. The method takes into consideration that if the first char is a number, then the **first object** to be placed in the list should be the double value of a substring of the argument from zero to the index of the first sign. The equivalent is done if the last char is a number at the last index of the list.
The above idea led me to create the project below:

```
package maths.calculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumGetter {
    static String expression;
    static ArrayList<Integer> preList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<Object> getNumber(String num) {
        expression = num;
        try {
            if (expression == null) {
                expression = "";
            }
            if (expression == "") {
                return list;
            }

            int condition = 0;
            for (char chars : expression.toCharArray()) {
                if (chars == '-' || chars == '+' || chars == '÷' || chars == '×' || chars == ')' || chars == '(') {
                    preList.add(condition);
                }
                condition++;
            }

            if (preList.size() != 0) {
                System.out.println(preList);
                if (expression.charAt(0) >= '0' && expression.charAt(0) <= '9') {
                    String local = expression.substring(0, preList.get(0));
                    list.add(Double.parseDouble(local));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < (preList.size() - 1); i++) {
                    int min = preList.get(i);
                    int next = preList.get(i + 1);
                    String local = expression.substring(min + 1, next);
                    if (local.length() == 0) {
                        list.add(expression.charAt(min));
                    } else {
                        double temp = Double.parseDouble(local);
                        list.add(expression.charAt(min));
                        list.add(temp);
                    }
                }
                if (expression.charAt(num.length() - 1) >= '0' && expression.charAt(num.length() - 1) <= '9') {
                    condition = preList.get(preList.size() - 1);
                    String local = expression.substring(condition);
                    list.add(expression.charAt(condition));
                    list.add(Double.parseDouble(local));
                }

            } else {
                list.add(Double.parseDouble(expression));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

The code above looked satisfactory enough even after I imported the class above and called the method getNumber as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import maths.calculator.NumGetter;

public class Text {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("(12+8)0");
        String one = "(12+8)0";
        ArrayList<Object> two = NumGetter.getNumber(one);
        System.out.println(two.toString());

    }
}
```

The problem lies in the output. In every case the Exception is thrown. Typically for the above, the out put was:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
    at maths.calculator.NumGetter.getNumber(NumGetter.java:43)
    at demo.Text.main(Text.java:12)
(12+8)0
[0, 3, 5]
```

However when I change the iteration `for (int i = 0; i < (preList.size() - 1); i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < (preList.size() - 2); i++)`, which by the way, should be incorrect, the result was quite close to the expected answer:

```
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at maths.calculator.NumGetter.getNumber(NumGetter.java:51)
    at demo.Text.main(Text.java:12)
(12+8)0
[0, 3, 5]
[(, 12.0, )]
```

What possibly have gone wrong please...
I very much need your good brains.

Comment: Suggestions.  (1) Use `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());` - that's what it's for.  (2) Step through your code with a debugger, if the exception stack trace doesn't make it clear what's happening.

Comment: *FYI:* `(chars < '0' || chars > '9' || chars != '.')` is always true. It *cannot* be false. That means `preList` will be a list of every index into `num`. Since `preList` will *never* have a `-1`, it also means that `list` will be the same. `number == ""` doesn't work (see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/5221149)). Which means that the first 20 lines of the method are all broken / useless.

Comment: All Java objects have a `toString()` method, so please use `two.toString()` to print its content.

Comment: @LHCHIN `println(two)` and `println(two.toString())` is exactly the same, since `println(Object)` is implemented to call `toString()` for you.

Comment: Remove the `try-catch` code. It's wrong, and it's hiding the error. Just get rid of it.

Comment: `if (number == "") {` doesn't look right to me.  Try `.equals()`.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, you are right! I misread the line of output message. @Isaac I think `number.substring(++min, next)` may cause `StringIndexOutOfBoundException`!

Comment: @Andreas `(chars < '0' || chars > '9' || chars != '.')` becomes false if chars is a numerical character

Comment: @LHCHIN  You're right. It was a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Isaac Really?!? Let `chars = '3'`, then we have `chars < '0'` *(false)*, `chars > '9' *(false)*, and `chars != '.'` *(true)*, then OR them together and you have ... **true**. --- The only time `chars != '.'` will be false is when `chars = '.'`, and then one of the other two will be true. I don't even need to look as an ASCII table to find out which one, because it's guaranteed that one of them will be true, which means that the entire expression is **always true**.

Comment: @Andreas You're right. 

Comment: @Andreas I seriously mistook. I think the right condition should be `if (chars < '0' || chars > '9' && chars != '.' )` so that it wouldn't be true for numerical characters and dots right?

Comment: @Isaac Do you know the operator precedence rules of `||` and `&&`? Most people get them wrong, or are at the very least unsure, so it's always best to use `()` when mixing `||` and `&&` in an expression. *(hint: your code is wrong)*

Comment: Poor title. Edit to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the line throwing the exception `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`  in the second iteration of the `for` loop:

`String local = number.substring(++min, next); //line throwing exception`

1st first iteration: `number.substring(1, 1);`

2nd iteration: `number.substring(2, 1);`

in the second iteration, it's throwing an exception because it's not allowed for the beginIndex of `substring` method to be greater than lastIndex. For more information please have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At long last. I can't believe the last bug was in the last if block:

```
String local = expression.substring(condition);
```

I reckon it is supposed to be:

```
String local = expression.substring(condition+1);
```

Thanks to everyone especially @Andreas